# How to Remove Project name From Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, .htaccess

I removed hash tag from url using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

and then i tried to resolve refresh problem using following code in my htcaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|txt)
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

Now the url looks like

```
http://diafriends.hostoi.com/test/
http://diafriends.hostoi.com/test/about
http://diafriends.hostoi.com/test/contact
```

Now i want to remove the `test` from above url. how can i do that???

[image]

Comment: Try removing `RewriteBase`

Comment: @Rayon Dabre I tried. Its not working.

Comment: You need to use the htaccess in your root folder instead of the test.

Comment: @Rayon Dabre I tried. That too not working.

Comment: @ starkeen I placed htcaccess file in root only. check above screen shot.

Comment: What happenes when you go to example.com/about ?

Comment: @starkeen Some Error throws. You can check http://diafriends.hostoi.com/about

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the default.php file of your hosting provider  from your folder and then add the following to htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|txt)
RewriteRule (.*) /test/index.html [L]
```